# s3.listObjectsV2 AccessDenied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

Hi I try to list all files in a "folder" of a S3 bucket. So I try:

```
const params = {
   Bucket: s3bucketname,
   Prefix: foldername + "/"
};

const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise()
console.log(data)
```

which give me an AccessDenied error.

Files itself are stored like this

```
const params = {
  Bucket: s3bucketname,
  Key: foldername + "/" + filename,
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  ACL: 'public-read',
  Body: data
};

await s3.upload(params, tags).promise();
```

and public available. which works fine. Also using

```
const params = {
  Bucket: s3bucketname,
  Key: folderfilename
};

await s3.headObject(params).promise()
```

works fine.

yml file looks like this

```
S3BucketampstoryscreenshotsPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties: 
    Bucket: 
      Ref: S3Bucketampstoryscreenshots
    PolicyDocument: 
      Statement: 
        - 
          Action: 
            - "s3:Get*"
          Effect: "Allow"
```

I tested multiple small variations but cant find the problem here?

Comment: You'll need s3:ListBucket to list the contents of the bucket.

Comment: What are the IAM permissions associated with the credentials being used? (This is _not_ the Bucket Policy, it is the IAM permissions associated with the IAM User being used to make the `ListBucketsV2()` call.)

Comment: s3:ListBucket was missing. Thanks. Will post the solution

Answer (score 0):

The ListBucket statement was needed. Important here to have Ref once with /* and once without /* Not having it set like that causes

> Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement (Service: Amazon
>   S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy;

This works in my case:

```
       PolicyDocument: 
          Statement: 
            - 
              Action: 
                - "s3:GetObject"
              Effect: "Allow"
              Resource: 
                Fn::Join: 
                  - ""
                  - 
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                    - 
                      Ref: "S3Bucketampstoryscreenshots"
                    - "/*"
              Principal: "*"
            - 
              Action: 
                - "s3:ListBucket"
              Effect: "Allow"
              Resource: 
                Fn::Join: 
                  - ""
                  - 
                    - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                    - 
                      Ref: "S3Bucketampstoryscreenshots"
              Principal: "*"
```

Thanks to jarmod for the hint